# How to make an existing AppleScript file to work as a service?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator

I made an AppleScript, saved it as a file in a specific folder on my hard drive. Now I want to assign a shortcut to it and looks like I have to make a Service via Automator, but the `Run AppleScript` asks me to put the code inside, while I want to execute the already existing .scpt file. How to do that?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, Automator is the best option here. To create the service follow these steps:

1. Open Automator and select Service:

   [image]
2. Search 'applescript' and drag the action to the right pane:

   [image]
3. Change `Service receives selected text` to `Service receives no input` so that it always appears in the Services menu:

   [image]
4. Replace `(* Your script goes here *)` with:

   ```
   do shell script "/usr/bin/osascript /path/to/your/script.scpt"
   ```

   if you wish to execute your existing `.scpt` file. Note that **osascript can't handle user interaction** like displaying a dialog window:

   [image]

   To overcome this limitation either use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484482/no-user-interaction-allowed-when-running-applescript-in-python) or simply replace `(* Your script goes here *)` with the contents of your script.
5. Save it:

   [image]
6. If you wish, you can assign a shortcut to your new service. Select Services>Services Preferences in Finder (or any open application):

   [image]
7. Assign a not so common shorcut:

   [image]
8. Now your service is accessible from any application through the shortcut you assigned in the previous step:

   [image]

If you ever want to get rid of the service open `~/Library/Services`, delete the service and empty the trash:

[image]

Comment: I said I want to execute existing script file, not to write it again into Automator.

Comment: I thought that copy/paste would be OK, but yes, you're right, it's stated clearly in your question. Use `osascript`, as explained in other answers.

Comment: @Nakilon I've added how to use `osascript` in Automator to run your `.scpt` file, a limitation and two workarounds.

Comment: I just did this.  It worked; but, it now takes 4 to 5 seconds to launch the script.  (When the code was saved directly in the workflow, it launched almost immediately.)  Any idea what causes this, or how make it launch faster?

Comment: @Zack When you run `/usr/bin/osascript /path/to/your/script.scpt` in a Terminal window, does the script also need 4 to 5 seconds to launch?

Comment: I'm not sure.  That particular script requires a selected email message.  I'm not sure how to fake that from the command line.

Comment: @Zack Launch Terminal and type `sleep 10 && /usr/bin/osascript /path/to/your/script.scpt`. This gives you 10 secs to switch to Mail and select the message before the script runs. Could you try it and report back?

Comment: Yes.  If I select a mail message, then run the script from the command line, it takes 6 seconds before the dialog box pops up.  When the code is saved directly in the Automator script, the dialog pops up less than 2 seconds after selecting the script from the services menu

Comment: @Zack Thanks, I don't know why `osascript` needs 4 additional seconds to execute your script, but Automator is not the cause of the delay, which was my concern. You may want to debug `osascript`, see https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045575/how-to-trace-system-calls-of-a-program-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 4):

In the script, add an `on run` argument:

```
on run
    -- do whatever the script does
end run
```

Then you can use the Automator "Run Shell Script" action, with the `osascript` command:

```
osascript /path/to/script.scpt
```

`osascript` is a command which executes AppleScript in the shell. You need the lines in the script to allow the script to be executed outside AppleScript editor.

Comment: You don't need to include an explicit run handler. All scripts have an implicit run handler. The reason why Automator's Run AppleScript action includes an explicit run handler might be because Automator uses the special `on run {input, arguments}` form, but even in Automator you can just remove the run handler.

Comment: @͏͏͏ I'm wondering if this ping gets to you. Kudos on the creative name selection.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you'd want to take a look at [This Service](http://wafflesoftware.net/thisservice/), which allows you to "create Mac OS X services from any script."

Comment: Can you provide an answer here rather than just a link

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend creating Automator services to assign shortcuts to scripts. There is a bug in in 10.7 and 10.8 where the keyboard shortcuts for Automator services don't always work until you hover over the services menu from the menu bar. There is also a relatively long (maybe 0.1 to 1 s) delay before services are run.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) for other ways to assign keyboard shortcuts to scripts. I use FastScripts and Alfred myself.

Comment: I  have never experienced this need to hover? do you have more details of what you are talking about

Comment: I'm not sure if it affects all OS X installations or all services, but I've ran into it multiple times on different installations, and it has mentioned by other people here and at Super User. Occasionally the keyboard shortcuts for all Automator services stop working (or nothing happens if you press them), but they start working again if you hover over the services menu from the menu bar, or if you for example select one service with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

You can RUN the existing script with a simple automator service like this.
And assign your shortcut from within the keyboard short cuts as normal.
Just remember some applications may need to be relaunched before they pick the shortcuts up.

example.

sayHello script:

```
say "hello"
```

Automator service:
[image]

Which in this example uses:

- **No input**
- **Any application.**

The Action is a **Run Shell Script**
The code just uses the unix command **osascript** and the path to the file.
***Pass input*** can be **to stdn** or **to argument**

Thats it nothing special needs to be done to the script.

For further details on the [osascript command look at the man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) for it. The man page give another example where you can pass arguments to the script.

Answer (score 0):

To develop a Service, you need some sort of software which will create a Service such as one of the following:

1. Automator to  create a .workflow
2. ThisService to create a .service
3. Xcode to create an .app

All of the above kinds of services are packages.  They are all folders which contain an plist that specifies the attributes of a Service.

Here is how I created a Service using Automator that uses a "Run AppleScript" Automator action to call an existing .script.

[image: Automator Service That Calls an Existing AppleScript]