# In automator, apple claims you can create a dialog with a progress bar. Is this feasible or outdated?

Tags: macos, automator

At this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayProgress.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH37-SW1

We see that there is a progress bar. I have been unable to create it. Is it deprecated?

[image]

UPDATE: Unable to change anything here:

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be aware that the link you posted refers to Script Editor, not Automator.

In Script Editor (programmed in either AppleScript or JavaScript) this is totally possible, just try the AppleScript sample code at the end of the developer article (open in Script Editor, save as application, run).

In Automator, only the progress of the respective steps within the Automator workflow can be shown (a rotating cog wheel or progress circle in the menu bar).

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Is there a way to add scripts as a quick action item? or is that only within the confines of automator?

Comment: You generally can (basically by inserting AppleScript code as an action in Automator), but the same limitations (no user interactions like dialogs from the AppleScript code fragments) still apply. Please see here for more info: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100642/how-to-make-an-existing-applescript-file-to-work-as-a-service

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Where should the action/automation happen/appear? Finder context menu, menu bar, Services menu? AppleScripts can appear in the Finder menu bar, for example. Or be auto-invoked as Folder Actions (not sure if this still works in 10.15, though, haven't used these in a while).

Comment: I have applescript that uploads a file via cURL. Then, I have a bash script that parses and reads the curl output to get the progress so far. I would like one of two options. The first I tried was to have a display notification tab popup showing the moving blue progress meter. The second is to have the gear icon on the menu bar show a completing circle corresponding to the progress so far. In both, I am unable to modify or am not even sure how to modify it. I've included a picture of what it shows above.

Comment: @user321627 According to your use case, Platypus is probably better suited. Platypus wraps (command line) scripts – w/o the need for an AppleScript wrapper – into a Mac application/droplet/menulet, including user interactions, graphical feedback (progress bars) etc. It's free/open source and has extensive documentation. https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus

Comment: thank you, just what I was trying to look for!!